# python optmize the following if elif statments

Tags: python

Have a python code that return 3 dataframes. i am using if-elif statements to comapre the df and return accordingly. For eg.

```
if (aaa_df is not None and bbb_df is not None and ccc_df is not None and ddd_df is not None:
    aaa_path = write_to_file(aaa_df, "aaa") # "aaa" is hte name of the file
    ddd_path = write_to_file(ddd_df, "ddd_mapping") # "ddd_mapping" is the name of the file
    bbb_path = write_to_file(bbb_df, "bbb")
    ccc_path = write_to_file(ccc_df, "ccc")
    return aaa_path, ddd_path, bbb_path, ccc_path
elif (aaa_df is None and bbb_df is None and ccc_df is not None and ddd_df is not None:
    aaa_path = f"The ID {id} has no aaa failure"
    ddd_path = write_to_file(ddd_df, "ddd_mapping")
    bbb_path = f"The ID {id} has no bbb failure"
    ccc_path = write_to_file(ccc_df, "ccc")
    return aaa_path, ddd_path, bbb_path, ccc_path
elif aaa_df is Not None and bbb_df is None and ccc_df is None and ddd_df is not None:
    aaa_path = write_to_file(aaa_df, "aaa")
    ddd_path = write_to_file(ddd_df, "ddd_mapping")
    bbb_path = f"The ID {id} has no bbb failure"
    ccc_path = f"The ID {id} has no ccc failure"
    return aaa_path, ddd_path, bbb_path, ccc_path
    
    ....
    ....
```

This way for 3 df .. i am having 8 combinations. Wherever ther is data i am writing it to a file, if not displaying appropriate msg to user.
Figuring out a way to optimize it. Is there any way ?

Comment: You probably want a proper datastructure for your dataframes, instead of four separate variables. Consider using a dict or a list of dataframes. Same for the paths of course.

Comment: This code has multiple syntax errors and undefined names (beyond just the df's). Please make a [mre] including complete valid code and some example input and output.

Comment: This is almost beside the point, but isn't that *four* dataframes, not three?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all dataframes and filenames in a dictionary and loop over the items in the dictionary. If the item is not `None` write to a file, else, return a failure. Here is an example implementation:

```py
filenames_to_df_map = {
    "aaa": aaa_df,
    "bbb": bbb_df,
    "ccc": ccc_df,
    "ddd_mapping": ddd_df,
}

results = []
for filename, df in filenames_to_df_map.items():
    if df is not None:
        results.append(write_to_file(df, filename))
    else:
        results.append(f"The ID {id} has no aaa failure")
return tuple(results)
```